# Why this query doesn't work?

Tags: php, sql

This is the query:

```
$fullDate = 2012-01-01;
$event = 'String';
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO agenda (date, event) VALUES ($fullDate, $event)");
```

It doesn't execute, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your DB layer have an option to report errors (or even better, throw them as exceptions)? If it does, see what errors are reported. If not, throw it away and find a better one.

Comment: what error it is giving and what is the type of columns (int or varchar)?

Comment: if (PEAR::isError($sql)) {
    die($sql->getMessage());
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must quote the inserted values:

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO agenda (date, event) VALUES ('$fullDate', '$event')");
```

Comment: Thank you, you misplaced one quote though: $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO agenda (date, event) VALUES ('$fullDate', '$event')");

Comment: You are right, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, this is safer to use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO agenda (date, event) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($fullDate, $event));
```

Comment: I was going to, but first wanted to have the query right ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO agenda (date, event) VALUES ('$fullDate', '$event)'");

if (PEAR::isError($sql)) 
{ 
die($sql->getMessage()); 
}
```